# How to run a batch on another server to copy a file to not shared directory

Tags: batch-file, copy, windows-server-2008-r2, virtual-directory

Plz help..

I am trying to run a batch on another server to copy a file to not shared directory (not UNC):

- there are two servers and two batch files: serv01 serv02 & bat1 bat2
- bat1 runs from serv01 and bat2 located on serv02 is called by bat1 from serv01
- bat2 is shared on serv02 so serv01 can see it
- I am trying to copy a file from serv01 to serv02. Copy **destination** path is not shared, but the bat2 is local on serv02 like, so the "double click" run will do the job.

bat1:

> call "\\serv2\folder\bat2.bat"

bat2:

> SET path01="\\serv01\deployment\serv02"
>
> SET path02="d:\application\ui"
>
> copy "%path01%\web.config" "%path02%\web.config"

I have tried **%~dp0** but this only uses the shared folder directory and can only copy to that folder(not desired location)

I tried PUSHD but this also creates a local virtual directory so in this case is path01 and this only, where I am trying to copy a file to **local** path02 (serv02)

I know there is always a problem with reading UNC`s and I couldnt find an answer to this on stack. Is there a way to run bat02 as local but still pull path01? As a "double click" run on the bat2 is working fine and does the job.

Many thanks!

Comment: Are you expecting bat2 to run on serv2? - It wont, it will run on the machine that executes it.

Comment: thx Alex, is there a way to copy then to path02? Without sharing it?

Comment: Fix the shares? .. psexec can run a batch file on a remote machine

Comment: I will look into psexec now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are an admin then everything is shared. The admin shares C$, D$, ..., N$ are admin hidden shares.

```
copy  "\\serv01\C$\folder\file.ext" "\\serv02\C$\folder\file.ext"
```

There are also Print$ and Admin$ shares. Type `net share` to see list.

To run a file remotely

```
wmic /node:serv02 process call create "cmd /c somefile.bat"
```

Comment: Brilliant! Alex`s way also works as I just tired it but I am an admin and "net share" list my drives...  Copy with D$ copies the files to a desired location(D drive). Both are good answers and like always, many thanks!